# std::unordered_map with shared pointer for auto destruction of entries

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map<int, custom_object* >` and have various shared pointers pointing to every entry in the `unordered_map`. The idea is so that once all the shared pointers are destructed, the entry will be removed from the `unordered_map`. `custom_object` currently contains the key so that it can remove the respective entry from the `unordered_map` upon destruction. I'd like to have a more elegant design, perhaps implementing an `unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<custom_object>>` instead. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You could use Boost Intrusive's auto_unlink feature for this.  You'd have to switch to a tree-based (ordered) map, but otherwise it might do what you need.  More specific details would help, perhaps some sample code showing your types exactly.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction. However, you have to figure out another trigger to remove `custom_object*`s from the `unordered_map`. The trigger you are using to remove them from the `unordered_map` would be gone.

Comment: Use a weak_ptr<> in your unordered_map<>.  When the last shared_ptr<> to an entry goes away, the weak_ptr<> will tell you the object is gone.  The down side is the items stay in the map.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom deleter for the `shared_ptr` that deletes the object and also removes it from the map:

```
class custom_object_deleter
{
public:
    custom_object_deleter(unordered_map<int, custom_object*>* map) :
        map(map)
    {
    }

    void operator()(custom_object* object)
    {
        // Remove object from map.
        delete object;
    }

private:
    unordered_map<int, custom_object*>* map
};
```

Then when you create a `custom_object` do this:

```
shared_ptr<custom_object> my_custom_object(new custom_object, custom_object_deleter(&map));
```

Sorry I just whipped this up quickly and haven't tested it for compile errors...

BUT, this is still not a very elegant solution. You may want to take a step back and check whether the design that requires this is really the best (and simplest!) one.